# QlikView Expression Query

Tags: mysql, logic, expression, qlikview

I'm working out a query but I cannot figure out.
When I select the MBProductName I  want to check the related transaction's product and do a count.

For example :

```
order_ID |  ProductName
   1     |     A
   1     |     B
   2     |     A
   2     |     B
   3     |     A
   3     |     C
   4     |     B
   4     |     C
```

Expected Results :
(Select A for MBProductName)

```
MBProductName | ProductName | Quantity
              |             |
              |    B        |   3
      A       |             |
              |    C        |   2
```

Currently I'm trying with :

```
If(Product_Name=MBProductName,0,Count(Distinct %%MarketBasket))
```

This results give me:

```
MBProductName | ProductName | Quantity
              |             |
              |    B        |   2
      A       |             |
              |    C        |   1
```

It does not Filter by the MBProductName

Can anyone help me with my Query?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please could you explain where `MBProductName` and `%%MarketBasket` come from and how they are derived?

Comment: @i_saw_drones Hi , I have marketBasket table which contain %%MArketBasket(order_ID) , MBproductName(same as product Name) and MBproductGroup(same as product Group). and another table Orders contain  %%MarketBasket(order_id),Product_id,quantity. Product table contain Product_id and ProductName

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest your aggregation correctly:

do this:

> Count(Distinct If(not Product_Name=MBProductName, %%MarketBasket))

"Count" is the aggregation, and "If" is the filter, you need to think of this as filtering first, then aggregating.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply . i have tried this but it still counting without filtering ..by filtering i also want to show the related product .( B and C as well as the quantity)

Comment: you may want to take a look at this question... i hope i can provide you enough information.. http://community.qlik.com/message/588433#588433